# Does GTK# have support for gestures?

Tags: mono, touch, gtk#

I've been looking through the source code (original, custom and generated) of Gtk#, the C# binding for Gtk+ under Mono/Linux, available at `github.com/mono/gtk-sharp`.

I can find *nothing* that seems to indicate it supports touch gestures available in Gtk+ itself, such as `GtkGestureSwipe`, `GtkGestureRotate` or `GtkGestureLongPress`. I can also find nothing to do with gestures on the [documentation page](http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=N%3AGtk).

I *thought* it may be because we were using an earlier branch but I can also find nothing on the master branch.

So, first up, does Gtk# actually expose the touch functionality of Gtk+?

And, if so, how do I go about using it?

Comment: Which version of Gtk+ supports gestures? As far as I know gtk-sharp still wraps Gtk 2.

Comment: @Skyler, as per https://github.com/mono/gtk-sharp/releases, gtk# 2.99.3 (and some earlier ones, but it's that one we're using) targets gtk+ 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time, apparently not.

While Gtk# 2.99.3 targets Gtk 3, real gesture support was not introduced into Gtk until about 3.14. Hence Gtk# knows nothing about them.

However, keep in mind that Gtk versions earlier than 3.14 will allow touch events to appear as mouse events so, if all you're after is simple gestures like click on screen or single-point drag, these can be made to show up as mouse clicks and mouse-down/mouse-move/mouse-up sequences.

This was done to make touch devices act in ways similar to mouse devices without actually having to change the source code.